# Keep ListView between activities

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView activity that start a new intent.

When Back pressed from the new intent we get back to the listview.

How do I keep the ListView without getting its items again? 
E.g. it is having ArrayAdapter..... that is filled from the net using some queries.
Can be in the list 100+ items.

Yoav

Comment: When **precisely** in the activity are you "getting its items"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Android stores activities by default in one task (until you use special flags to start activity. [More](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)). This means that if you press back button it should be filled in with the same data. But in this case it depends in which method you fill ListView. If you do this in onResume() then the ListView will be filled in all the time. If you do this in onCreate() then the ListView will be filled only if the activity is created for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Where you populate your list? If you populate in the onResume(), you should move it to the onCreate in order to avoid repopulating the list. Moreover in any case you can cache the results in order not to fetch them every time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Caching the results? But if I have lots of informatin? I do image caching... What you suggest is to store the entire list info in the memory and repopulate it? But if it is CursorAdapter for the list? In this case I can re-query from the DB. But how can I get to the previous position?